# use bash or awk to replace part of a string

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following example lines in a file:

```
sweet_25 2 0 4
guy_guy 2 4 6
ging_ging 0 0 3
moat_2 0 1 0
```

I want to process the file and have the following output:

```
sweet_25 2 0 4
guy 2 4 6
ging 0 0 3
moat_2 0 1 0
```

Notice that the required effect happened in lines 2 and 3 - that an underscore and text follwing a text is remove on lines where this pattern occurs.

I have not succeeded with the follwing:

```
sed -E 's/([a-zA-Z])_[a-zA-Z]/$1/g' file.txt >out.txt
```

Any bash or awk advice will be welcome.Thanks

Comment: so is your criteria to make the change on lines 2 and 3 or the all but the first and last lines or all lines that start with g or lines that have the same string either side of the _ or lines that only have alphabetic chars in the part after the _  or something else? All answers so far are making different guesses so please [edit] your question to state your requirements, don't assume we can guess what you want to do from reading input/output and code that doesn't do whatever it is you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to replace the whole word after the underscore, you have to repeat the character class one or more times using `[a-zA-Z]+` and use `\1` in the replacement.

```
sed -E 's/([a-zA-Z])_[a-zA-Z]+/\1/g' file.txt >out.txt
```

If the words should be the same before and after the underscore, you can use a repeating capture group with a backreference.

If you only want to do this for the start of the string you can prepend `^` to the pattern and omit the `/g` at the end of the sed command.

```
sed -E 's/([a-zA-Z]+)(_\1)+/\1/g' file.txt >out.txt
```

The pattern matches:

- `([a-zA-Z]+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1 or more occurrences of a char a-zA-Z
- `(_\1)+` Capture group 2, repeat matching `_` and the same text captured by group 1

The file *out.txt* will contain:

```
sweet_25 2 0 4
guy 2 4 6
ging 0 0 3
moat_2 0 1 0
```

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk 'split($1,arr,"_") && arr[1] == arr[2]{$1=arr[1]} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, using `awk`'s `split` function that splits 1st field into an array named `arr` with delimiter `_` AND then checking condition if 1st element of arr is EQAUL to 2nd element of arr then save only 1st element of arr to first field(`$1`) and by mentioning `1` printing edited/non-edited lines.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it more simply, like this:

```
sed -E 's/_[a-zA-Z]+//' file.txt >out.txt
```

This just replaces an underscore followed by any number of alphabetical characters with nothing.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'NR~/^[23]$/{sub(/_[^ ]+/,"")} 1' file
sweet_25 2 0 4
guy 2 4 6
ging 0 0 3
moat_2 0 1 0
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do:

```
awk '$1~/[[:alpha:]]_[[:alpha:]]/{sub(/_.*/,"",$1)} 1' file
```

Prints:

```
sweet_25 2 0 4
guy 2 4 6
ging 0 0 3
moat_2 0 1 0
```